# Rewriting URL by appending .html suffix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I'm attempting to use mod_rewrite with Apache 2.4 to append the suffix `.html` to request URIs.

The URIs that should be rewritten are very simple and take the following form:

`http://host.domain/page/`

The above needs to be rewritten to `http://host.domain/page.html`. Only constraint is that the rewriting logic must ignore URIs referencing actual files or directories.

So far the rewriting snippet I came up with works fine if there is **no trailing slash**, however if one is present Apache emits a 404 and the following error message:

`The requested URL /redirect:/about.html was not found on this server.`

(the above happens when the URI is `http://localhost/about/`)

Could someone help me debug this?  Why is Apache prepending `/redirect:`?

Here's a very simple snippet that reproduces the symptoms:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ /$1 [C]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L,R=301] # Tried without R=301 too

# This doesn't work either.
# RewriteRule ^about/$ /about.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# strip trailing slash from non-directoies
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# make sure corresponding html file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Could you please explain where I was going wrong above? For instance, why doesn't chaining the first rule to remove the trailing slash work?

Comment: There was no need to use `C` flag in your first rule and better to use `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f` to make sure corresponding html file exists.