Non valid pages 301 redirect before they 404
I'm trying to fix the issue of our non valid extensionless requests getting a 301 redirect before they 404. For example, if a user requests https://example.com/content/go/some-non-page it 301 redirects to https://example.com/content/go/some-non-page.html and then provides a 404.
Any ideas appreciated - I have tried eliminating the R=301 flag (even though I would like to retain that) and instead used a PT flag, but then I can't get the .html extension to work. I have also tried adding each of these conditions (one at a time) in to check for actual pages, but they don't seem to work / break the ruleset:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# Handle requests to pages ending with non-trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/go/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.json$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.sjson$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.html [R=301,L]

# Handle requests to pages ending with trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/go/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.json$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.sjson$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ $1.html [R=301,L]

# Handle requests to pages ending with trailing slash after .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/go/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*.html/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.json$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.sjson$
RewriteRule ^(.*).html/(.*) /content/go/en/error/error-404.html [R=404,L]


Your rules have a condition to match URI with /content/go/ but your example URI doesn't have /content/go/

I will fix that

You need to use another RewriteCond that checks if the requested URI with .html appended matches an existing file, using the f flag. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397122/1427878

When you say existing file - i'm assuming this is the same as a website page? If so, this is exactly what I was needing to do

So problem solved?

Unfortunately not. I've tried adding each of these (one at a time to my rules) to see if they filter out only the actual pages, but it just breaks the rules:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

This is close, but not quite there - it only works on the first directory level and then further directories don't meet the condition for some reason.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}
